# Is there any lib for python that will get me the synonyms of a word?

Tags: python, nlp, synonym

Is there any api/lib for python that will get me the synonyms of a word?

For example if i have the word "house" it will return "building, domicile, mansion, etc..."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258652/how-to-get-synonyms-from-nltk-wordnet-python/67401089#67401089

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and Wordnet can help: e.g., per [this article](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2009/12/28/experimenting-with-nltk),

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

dog = wordnet.synset('dog.n.01')
print(dog.lemma_names())
```

prints:

```
['dog', 'domestic_dog', 'Canis_familiaris']
```

Comment: What if it's arbitrary word and you don't know its part of speech ahead of time?

Answer (score 4):

**Update: as @deweydb has pointed out, as of Feb 10th 2022, this solution no longer works.**

You can also use [PyDictionary](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary)

For example,

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary 
dictionary=PyDictionary() 
print (dictionary.synonym("good"))
```

The output is

```
[u'great', u'satisfying', u'exceptional', u'positive', u'acceptable']
```

This is actually fetching words from [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com) and is a little slow. Multi-threading may help accelerate it.

Comment: As with all scrapers, eventually they die. As of Feb 10th 2022, this solution no longer works.