# All synonyms for word in python?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

The code to get the synonyms of a word in python is say:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

dog = wordnet.synset('dog.n.01')
print dog.lemma_names

>>['dog', 'domestic_dog', 'Canis_familiaris']
```

However dog.n.02 gives different words. For any words i can't know how many words there may be. How can i return all of the synonyms for a word?

Answer (score 23):

Using `wn.synset('dog.n.1').lemma_names` is the correct way to access the **synonyms of a sense**. **It's because a word has many senses and it's more appropriate to list synonyms of a particular meaning/sense.** To enumerate words with similar meanings, possibly you can also look at the hyponyms.

Sadly, the size of Wordnet is very limited so there are very few lemma_names available for each senses.

Using Wordnet as a dictionary/thesarus is not very apt per se, because it was developed as an inventory of sense/meaning rather than a inventory of words. However you can use access the a particular sense and several (not a lot) related words to the sense. One can use Wordnet as a:

**Dictionary:** given a word, what are the different meaning of the word

```
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('dog')):
  print "Meaning",i, "NLTK ID:", j.name
  print "Definition:",j.definition
```

**Thesarus:** given a word, what are the different words **for each meaning** of the word

```
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('dog')):
  print "Meaning",i, "NLTK ID:", j.name
  print "Definition:",j.definition
  print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names)
  print
```

**Ontology:** given a word, what are the hyponyms (i.e. sub-types) and hypernyms (i.e. super-types).

```
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('dog')):
  print "Meaning",i, "NLTK ID:", j.name
  print "Hypernyms:", ", ".join(list(chain(*[l.lemma_names for l in j.hypernyms()])))
  print "Hyponyms:", ", ".join(list(chain(*[l.lemma_names for l in j.hyponyms()])))
  print
```

**[Ontology Output]**

```
Meaning 0 NLTK ID: dog.n.01
Hypernyms words domestic_animal, domesticated_animal, canine, canid
Hyponyms puppy, Great_Pyrenees, basenji, Newfoundland, Newfoundland_dog, lapdog, poodle, poodle_dog, Leonberg, toy_dog, toy, spitz, pooch, doggie, doggy, barker, bow-wow, cur, mongrel, mutt, Mexican_hairless, hunting_dog, working_dog, dalmatian, coach_dog, carriage_dog, pug, pug-dog, corgi, Welsh_corgi, griffon, Brussels_griffon, Belgian_griffon

Meaning 1 NLTK ID: frump.n.01
Hypernyms: unpleasant_woman, disagreeable_woman
Hyponyms: 

Meaning 2 NLTK ID: dog.n.03
Hypernyms: chap, fellow, feller, fella, lad, gent, blighter, cuss, bloke
Hyponyms: 

Meaning 3 NLTK ID: cad.n.01
Hypernyms: villain, scoundrel
Hyponyms: perisher
```

Comment: To make it work in NLTK 2.7.10, you need to replace `.name` with `.name()`, `.definition` with `.definition()` and `.lemma_names` with `.lemma_names()`.

Comment: from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn; from itertools import chain

Answer (score 6):

Note [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258889/583834):

```
>>> wn.synsets('small')
[Synset('small.n.01'),
 Synset('small.n.02'),
 Synset('small.a.01'),
 Synset('minor.s.10'),
 Synset('little.s.03'),
 Synset('small.s.04'),
 Synset('humble.s.01'),
 Synset('little.s.07'),
 Synset('little.s.05'),
 Synset('small.s.08'),
 Synset('modest.s.02'),
 Synset('belittled.s.01'),
 Synset('small.r.01')]
```

Keep in mind that in your code you were trying to get the lemmas, but that's one level too deep for what you want. **The synset level is about meaning, while the lemma level gives you words.** [In other words](http://www.quora.com/Dictionaries/In-WordNet-whats-the-difference-between-a-sense-and-a-lemma):

> In WordNet (and I’m speaking of English WordNet here, though I think
>   the ones in other langauges are similarly organized) a lemma has
>   senses. Specifically, a lemma (that is, a base word form that is
>   indexed in WordNet) has exactly as many senses as the number of
>   synsets that it participates in. Conversely, and as you say, synsets
>   contain one more more lemmas, which means that multiple lemmas (words)
>   can represent the same sense, or meaning.

Also have a look at the [NLTK's WordNet how to](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html) for a few more ways of exploring around a meaning or a word.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation suggests](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

```
wordnet.synsets('dog')
```

to get all synsets for dog.

Comment: The link is now dead.