# Get synonyms from synset returns error - Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to get synonyms of a given word using Wordnet. The problem is that despite I'm doing the same as is written here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348973/all-synonyms-for-word-in-python), it returns error.

Here is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import nltk

dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
print dog.lemma_names

>>> <bound method Synset.lemma_names of Synset('dog.n.01')>


for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('small')):
    print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names)

>>> Synonyms: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Python/PycharmProjects/PribliznostneVyhladavanie/testy.py", line 38, in         <module>
    print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names)
TypeError
```

The only thing I want is to put a word and get a list of synonyms. Does anybody knows whats wrong?

EDIT: I tried another advice which I found here on stackoverflow. It does not work either.

```
syns = wn.synsets('car')
print [l.name for s in syns for l in s.lemmas]

>>> TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The examples you found are for an earlier version of nltk. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which version of nltk are you using (try `print nltk.__version`)? Are you using python 2 or python 3? It seems that in the version you are using, `lemma_names` is a method and not an attribute (this is the case in nltk 3.0 for Python 3). If this is the case then you can probably fix your code by using this instead:

```
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('small')):
    print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names())
```

Comment: Version: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0) And thanks, it helped me.

Comment: Ok so it seems that you are using nltk 3 for Python 2. I have updated the code in my answer for your case.

Comment: This solved my problem in nltk 3.2 and python 2.7. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 & 3 versions lemmas and lemma_names don't work as they are methods. You have to use lemmas() and lemma_names() instead.

For eg -

`dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
print dog.lemma_names()`