# How to get similar words related to one word?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim, spacy

I am trying to solve a nlp problem where i have a dict of words like :

```
list_1={'phone':'android','chair':'netflit','charger':'macbook','laptop','sony'}
```

Now if input is 'phone' i can easily use 'in' operator to get the description of phone and its data by key but problem is if input is something like  'phones' or 'Phones' .

I want if i input  'phone' then i get words like

```
'phone' ==> 'Phones','phones','Phone','Phone's','phone's'
```

I don't know which word2vec i can use and which nlp module can provide solution like this.

second issue is if i give a word 'Dog' can i get words like 'Puppy','Kitty','Dog','dog' etc ?

I tried something like this but its giving synonyms :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
for ss in wn.synsets('phone'): # Each synset represents a diff concept.
    print(ss)
```

but its returning :

```
Synset('telephone.n.01')
Synset('phone.n.02')
Synset('earphone.n.01')
Synset('call.v.03')
```

Instead i wanted :

```
'phone' ==> 'Phones','phones','Phone','Phone's','phone's'
```

Answer (score 5):

WordNet indexes concepts (aka `Synsets`) not words.

Use `lemma_names()` to access root words (aka `Lemma`) in WordNet.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> for ss in wn.synsets('phone'): # Each synset represents a diff concept.
...     print(ss.lemma_names())
... 
['telephone', 'phone', 'telephone_set']
['phone', 'speech_sound', 'sound']
['earphone', 'earpiece', 'headphone', 'phone']
['call', 'telephone', 'call_up', 'phone', 'ring']
```

**Lemma being the root form or a word shouldn't have additional affixes so you'll not find plural or different form of the words as you have listed in the list of words you wanted.**

See also:

- https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(linguistics)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet
- [All synonyms for word in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348973/all-synonyms-for-word-in-python)

Also, words are ambiguous and may need to be disambiguated by context or my Parts-of-Speech (POS) before you can get "similar" words, e.g you see that "phone" in the verb meaning is not exactly the same meaning as phone as in the "noun".

```
>>> for ss in wn.synsets('phone'): # Each synset represents a diff concept.
...     print(ss.lemma_names(), '\t', ss.definition())
... 
['telephone', 'phone', 'telephone_set']      electronic equipment that converts sound into electrical signals that can be transmitted over distances and then converts received signals back into sounds
['phone', 'speech_sound', 'sound']   (phonetics) an individual sound unit of speech without concern as to whether or not it is a phoneme of some language
['earphone', 'earpiece', 'headphone', 'phone']   electro-acoustic transducer for converting electric signals into sounds; it is held over or inserted into the ear
['call', 'telephone', 'call_up', 'phone', 'ring']    get or try to get into communication (with someone) by telephone
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the second question, does it?

Comment: What is the second question? ;P

Comment: *"second issue is if i give a word 'Dog' can i get words like 'Puppy','Kitty','Dog','dog' etc ?"* essentially how to get a list of most similar words, provided the initial word as input - the question as per title.