# How to get Synonyms for ngrams using sentiwordnet in nltk Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram, synonym

**I've been trying**
on how to get synonyms for the words I pass. That's an easy piece of cake for wordnet to do. However I'm trying and failing with bigrams

> viz. 'i tried', 'horrible food', 'people go'

**I looked for these**
to learn more on sentiwordnet, since I read [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.lin.LinThesaurusCorpusReader.synonyms). Perhaps, there are no examples on how to use it. 
Went on for [source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/sentiwordnet.html) too, yet I'm here.

**I wrote**
the code for doing it in foll. way, point out what needs correction:

```
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn
sentisynset = swn.senti_synset('so horrible')
print(sentisynset)
```

Well, this clear returns `ValeError`, not sure why though.

Also, I tried this:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader.lin import LinThesaurusCorpusReader as ltcr
synon = ltcr.synonyms(ngram='so horrible')
print(synon)
```

and this returns `TypeError`, asking me for `self` parameter to be filled.

Comment: Related, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009296/note-taking-program-with-nltk-and-wordnet-doesnt-work-error-message-says-its-be/50018894#50018894

Comment: Wordnets indexed lemmas not words/ngrams =)

Comment: Interface to sentiwordnet http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html

Comment: Hi @alvas, I have been at Interface sentiwordnet page, however doesn't really solve my problem. Besides, the StackOF question has many details, but none of them directly takes in a bigram as input and then results with their synonyms, is it not possible? and ('^_^) Didn't get the 2nd comment. any more help? please?

Comment: @alvas any light you can shed on ConceptNet in python? I read that might help too.