# categorize/ get hypernym type word using wordnet in python

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

In my project I have to find the category/hypernym type of a specific word.

For example if i type Sushi/lion, the output will show food/animal. The main concept is to categorize the word.  So, how can I get this using nltk and WordNet in Python?

Comment: I suggest changing the title of your question to "Get hypernym of a word..." or "Get common hypernym of two words...", depending on what your intentions are. Word types are nouns, verbs, adjectives and so on, and people might not find what they are looking for here.

Comment: My question is actually not to get hypernym of word or "Get common hypernym of two words" . But basically I don't know the actual title for my desired output. thats why I gave an example. If you understand my question's example could you please help me to get the title for this question?  @WolfgangK

Comment: If the task is to get from "apple" to "food", I would say the correct term for that task is either categorization (in general) or finding the hypernym (in nltk context). Maybe update your question to show a sample of your data or give more context to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure if your goal is achievable with an out-of-the-box solution since the abstraction level needed is quite high. In terms of nltk/wordnet, you are looking for the hypernym (supertype/superordinate) of a word. For example, the hypernym of "sushi" might be "seafood" on a first level, whereas "apple" might be just a "fruit". Probably you will have to go through several levels of hypernyms to arrive at your desired output. As a starting point to get the hypernyms, you can use this code (see [All synonyms for word in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348973/all-synonyms-for-word-in-python/19383914#19383914)):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from itertools import chain

for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('apple')):
    print('Meaning', i, 'NLTK ID', j.name())
    print('Definition:', j.definition())
    print('Hypernyms:', ', '.join(list(chain(*[l.lemma_names() for l in j.hypernyms()]))))
```

Notice also that one single word can have different meanings with different hypernyms, which further complicates your task.

**EDIT**

Actually, there is an out-of-the-box solution to this problem called `lowest_common_hypernym`:

```
wn.synset('apple.n.01').lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synset('sushi.n.01'))
```

While this function is pretty nice, it does not necessarily return the most obvious solution. Here, it returns `[Synset('matter.n.03')]`.

Comment: Though it's not my desired output but it's close to my answer. So I marked this answer as an accepted answer. @WolfgangK