# How to get a list of parts of speech and words from Princeton English WordNet?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, wordnet, part-of-speech

I'd like a complete list of parts of speech (e.g., adj., adv., and .v) for English words. All I need is just a TSV table with two columns, with the first column the word and the second column POS.

I know that wordnet should contain such information. But it contains more than what I needed. I am not sure which file I should use.

https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download

Does anybody know a convenience-to-use file that contains English words and their POS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wordnet doesn't give you "word" per say but lemmas.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

for ss in wn.all_synsets():
    for lemma in ss.lemma_names():
        print(ss.offset() + '\t' + ss.pos() +'\t' + lemma)
```

See

- [All synonyms for word in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348973/all-synonyms-for-word-in-python)
- [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers)
- https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk