# Synsets for a word in WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to work on finding **`Synsets`** in `WordNet (which is Lexical database for English)` using python.

Here is the code which I am trying to find synsets and example of that synsets (passed as parameter):

```
 from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonynm=wordnet.synsets('friend')[2]#? wt does[0] mean
synonynm.name() #related synonyms wrds
synonynm.definition() #definition of passed words
wordnet.synsets('friend')[0].examples()
```

When I use index **`wordnet.synsets('friend')[0]`** or **`wordnet.synsets('friend')[1]`** or **`wordnet.synsets('friend')[2]`**

it gives me same output that can be viewed here

```
['he was my best friend at the university']
```

but if did place braces empty it showed error `[]`

so i just want to know is the difference in uasge between

```
synonynm=wordnet.synsets('friend')[0]
```

and this

```
wordnet.synsets('friend')[1]
```

I would be grateful for your guidance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348973/all-synonyms-for-word-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wordnet.synsets('friend')` returns a list of Synsets:

```
[Synset('friend.n.01'), Synset('ally.n.02'), Synset('acquaintance.n.03'), Synset('supporter.n.01'), Synset('friend.n.05')]
```

You can then access each Synset in the list via its index eg. the first Synset in the list is:

```
wordnet.synsets('friend')[0] # Synset('friend.n.01')
wordnet.synsets('friend')[0].name() # friend.n.01
wordnet.synsets('friend')[0].definition() # a person you know well and regard with affection and trust
wordnet.synsets('friend')[0].examples() # ['he was my best friend at the university']
```

Here's a code snippet that prints the name, definition and examples for each Synset in the list:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
for result in wordnet.synsets('friend'):
    print(result.name(), result.definition(), result.examples())
```

Output:

```
friend.n.01 a person you know well and regard with affection and trust ['he was my best friend at the university']
ally.n.02 an associate who provides cooperation or assistance ["he's a good ally in fight"]
acquaintance.n.03 a person with whom you are acquainted ['I have trouble remembering the names of all my acquaintances', 'we are friends of the family']
supporter.n.01 a person who backs a politician or a team etc. ['all their supporters came out for the game', 'they are friends of the library']
friend.n.05 a member of the Religious Society of Friends founded by George Fox (the Friends have never called themselves Quakers) []
```

Note that in your code, if you want the examples for index 2 in the list of Synsets, you should do:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
synonynm=wordnet.synsets('friend')[2]
synonynm.name() #related synonyms words
synonynm.definition() #definition of passed words
synonynm.examples()
```