# how to flatten a 2D list to 1D without using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list looks like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]]
```

and I want to flatten it into `[1,2,3,1,2,1,4,5,6,7]`

is there a light weight function to do this without using numpy?

Comment: If the goal is to do something *without* Numpy, then it *isn't* a Numpy question and *shouldn't* be tagged that way. That said, it seems strange to *expect* Numpy to be helpful here, since the inputs aren't the same length and thus there's no approach involving a *rectangular* array. Sure, the elements shown here are all integers, but they'd have to be boxed anyway unless we *start with* Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Without numpy ( [`ndarray.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) ) one way would be using  [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) which is an alternate constructor for `itertools.chain` :

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]]))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or as another yet Pythonic approach you can use a **list comprehension** :

```
[j for sub in [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]] for j in sub]
```

Another functional approach very suitable for short lists could also be `reduce` in Python2 and `functools.reduce` in Python3 (**don't use this for long lists**):

```
In [4]: from functools import reduce # Python3

In [5]: reduce(lambda x,y :x+y ,[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

To make it slightly faster you can use `operator.add`, which is built-in, instead of `lambda`:

```
In [6]: from operator import add

In [7]: reduce(add ,[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [8]: %timeit reduce(lambda x,y :x+y ,[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])
789 ns ± 7.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit reduce(add ,[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])
635 ns ± 4.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

benchmark:

```
:~$ python -m timeit "from itertools import chain;chain.from_iterable([[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "reduce(lambda x,y :x+y ,[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.791 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "[j for i in [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]] for j in i]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.784 usec per loop
```

A benchmark on @Will's answer that used `sum` (its fast for short list but not for long list) :

```
:~$ python -m timeit "sum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.575 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "sum([range(100),range(100)], [])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.27 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "reduce(lambda x,y :x+y ,[range(100),range(100)])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: how does `sum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [])` compare to these?

Comment: @will for short lists its faster than reduce but for longer lists its not!

Comment: @Kasramvd Awesome response! But I got confused about how a non-nested list comprehension like `[j for i in [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]] for j in i]` could flatten the 2d list, could you give some more illustration?

Comment: @WeisiZhan List comprehensions of this kind are usually called nested because of the nested `for` loops. In order to understand the behavior of such list comprehensions you can use a nested for lop and append all the items to a previously defined list. Like, `lst = []; for sublist in all_lists: for item in sublist: lst.append(item)`

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks! :-)

Comment: `[j for sub in [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,4,5,6,7]] for j in sub]` This is the way :-)

Comment: To me the list comprehension one doesn't _read right_. It feels something is off about it - I always seem to get it wrong and end up googling. To me this reads right `[x for x in row for row in matrix]`, but I guess I just have rewire my brain with the way it is.

Answer (score 97):

For just a list like this, my favourite neat little trick is just to use `sum`;

`sum` has an optional argument: `sum(iterable [, start])`, so you can do:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
print sum(list_of_lists, []) # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

this works because the `+` operator happens to be the concatenation operator for lists, and you've told it that the starting value is `[]` - an empty list.

but the documentaion for [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) advises that you use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) instead, as it's much clearer.

Comment: how to do for list of strings ?

Comment: @pyd the code above works for any object type... why not test before asking?

Comment: my_list looks like `["A",["B","C"],"D",["E","F"]]` it was not working,

Comment: @pyd it's not working because "A" isn't a list but ["B","C"] is so when it tried to use + to concatenate them it fails (you can't add a string to a list)

Comment: Using `+` as concatenation in `sum`, it is like a miracle. Thank you. This is great solution for any list of lists.

Comment: This is as Pythonic as it gets.

Comment: @unltd_J i used to think it was pythonic, but now i much prefer readability over perl-esque line noise. nowadays i would go with something from the itertools package.

Comment: This is slow than `extend(row[::-1])`

Answer (score 9):

This will work in your particular case. A recursive function would work best if you have multiple levels of nested iterables.

```
def flatten(input):
    new_list = []
    for i in input:
        for j in i:
            new_list.append(j)
    return new_list
```

Comment: This is the only solution that actually works for deeply nested lists.