# Auto-completing Strings in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I was wondering if there was some function where I could put in a string and if this string had words that it could auto-complete to (in the english language) it would return true (for example if the string is "bl" then this function would return true since "blue" is a word) and if not (say the string is "blszc") then it would return false.

Comment: There's certainly not a built in function for that. But you can write your own, use a webservice, maybe there's even a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You will need an inbuild dictionary/corpus of words for autocompleting the words.
   You can use NLTK with Wordnet : http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html
2. You would need a scoring to score the suggestions , it could be lexicographical i.e. for "bl"  suggestions like "blaze" , "blah" would appear before "blue" .
   Or it could be based on importance of the word in common language. To roughly do that you can use frequency distribution of the words in [Brown Corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus) in NLTK as starting point . ( example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234480/533399 )
3. You would need a fast rest service as autocomplete happens on every keystroke ( or every few keystrokes if throttled, and the user is typing very fast ). For this you would need to store your data in a data store which has retreival's optimized for prefixes 'eg' blu shall return 'blue','blunt' etc . My suggestion would be Solr/ElasticSearch
   ( this would in future also allow you to have features of spelling correction or 'did you mean' )
4. As a simple optimization, you shall limit your autocomplete suggestions to first 5-10 results found for any prefix, it shall be your ranking that should be so good that the best match appears at higher positions in the suggestion list.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually what I started attempting. I'm not a programmer, but would the fastest way to see if there is at least one word that it could auto-complete to be: autocomp_test=any(string in s for s in words.words()) where it returns true if a word exists that it could auto-complete to. (where words.words is the nltk english dictionary)

Comment: The fastest way is Solr or ElasticSearch, or any custom prefix tree based in-memory structure you can create.